# Is it possible to use the PayPal API to send money to a random account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a PayPal account, say, someaccount@somewhere.com.

I also have 5 different PayPal accounts stored in a database that were entered by random users. I would like to send all of these accounts some money.

Can this be automated using the PayPal API?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this is the PayPal Masspay API; that is exactly what it is for. This API has been around for 10+ years:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayOverview/

There is also the brand-new REST API PayPal Payouts:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/

This can also be done with Adaptive Payments and probably several other products.